# Evalute definite Integration with singular point

Tags: integration

Evalute Definite integration with singular point

$$\int^{\sqrt{2}} 
_{1} \dfrac{\ln t}{t-1}\ dt$$

I am not evalute above integration. Can some please help me?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: If my answer helped you feel free to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

One can first start re writing the integral as this:
$$\int _1^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\ln \left(t\right)}{t-1}\:dt=\int _0^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\ln \left(t\right)}{t-1}\:dt-\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(t\right)}{t-1}\:dt$$
The $2$nd integral is a very well known $\zeta \left(2\right)$ and for the $1$st one let's use integration by parts.
$$=\frac{\ln \left(2\right)\ln \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)}{2}-\int _0^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\ln \left(1-t\right)}{t}\:dt-\zeta \left(2\right)$$
For that integral let's make use of the dilogarithm function.
$$=\frac{\ln \left(2\right)\ln \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)}{2}+\text{Li}_2\left(\sqrt{2}\right)-\zeta \left(2\right)$$
So your integral is:
$$\boxed{\int _1^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\ln \left(t\right)}{t-1}\:dt=\frac{\ln \left(2\right)\ln \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)}{2}+\text{Li}_2\left(\sqrt{2}\right)-\zeta \left(2\right)\approx0.3777568}$$